# Converting SAS incremental counter creation to Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, sas

I am a new Python user with about 20 years of SAS experience. I am trying to convert some processes over to Python from SAS. I've come across a number of challenges so far, but I've been able to find most of the solutions I need here (so thank you for that, SO!) But the one I came across today is proving to be a bit more challenging in that I can't seem to find a similar example (may be just a limitation on my search terms.) Anyway, here is the problem. I have some SAS code that applies a counter that iterates over one variable within another. So if I have a table with variables a & b:
So if I have a table with variables a & b

[image: So if I have a table with variables a & b]

I want to add a counter that iterates over "b" within "a"
[image: I want to add a counter that iterates over "b" within "a"]

In SAS, I know this code will work:

```
proc sort data=f1; 
by a b; 
run;

data f1;
set f1;
by a b;
if first.b then codeord=0;
codeord+1;
run;
```

Can anyone give me a way to do this in Python 3.X? I've seen a few things that I think might get me (e.g., "shift" function) but so far I have not been able to get anything to work. Thank you!

Comment: When you say you have a table, what do you mean?  Is the table a pandas dataframe, a numpy array, a list of lists, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has cumcount function to solve the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
df['codeord']=df.groupby(['a','b']).b.cumcount()+1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! I figured it would be a one line solution that I was just completely ignorant of. I'm finding that Python is a great language that can do an awful lot with just a few lines of code, but I'm also learning that I need to get better at constructing searches for things I need to do - I searched on "create a cumulative count for one variable over another" but that didn't lead me to this. Thank you again! Very helpful!